# Request Google Doc body content; request OK but body is empty

Tags: angular, google-api, httpclient

try to get document content body from Google Drive (Docs) with Angular 4 (http: HttpClient) and Google API (Drive).

```
this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileIDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD/export', {
        observe: 'response',
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('key', 'KEYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY')
            .set('mimeType', 'text/plain'),
        })
        .subscribe(resp => {
            this.data = resp;
            console.log(resp);
        });
```

Ausgabe:

```
{…}body: null 
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: HttpHeaders/this.lazyInit() }ok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 4url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/filIDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD/export?key=keyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&mimeType=text/plain"__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpResponse(), clone: ../../../common/@angular/common/http.es5.js/HttpResponse.prototype.clone() } rechtespalte.component.ts:64:16
```

As you can see request is OK but body keeps empty.

Just requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileIDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD responses filename an some other data.

How I get the content of the GoogleDoc?